# How to change the column position of auto generated columns in GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

In a `GridView` I set `AutoGenerated = true`. I placed one button inside the item template.

Auto generated columns always starts at column 2.

But is there a way to set `AutoGenerated` columns always starts at column 1 and button inside item template should be last column?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
DataGridView.Columns["ColumnName"].DisplayIndex = 1;
```